# ionic 3.2 - How to disable scroll of ion-content?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am developing an app in Ionic 3.2 version. I have a ion-refresher inside ion-scroll. I want to disable scrolling of `ion-content` and want to show the `ion-refresher` inside the `ion-scroll` when scroll the `ion-list`. But it fails.

- I tried `no-bounce` (`<ion-content no-bounce>`) and `disable-scroll` (`<ion-content disable-scroll>`) but still content is scrolling
- I tried to put `ion-fixed` inside `content` and inside a `div` just below the `content`. But then the `ion-refresher` not working.
- I tried `scroll="false"` (like in ionic 1.0) but still scrolling

Below the code;

```
    <ion-content scroll="false">
    <ion-scroll scrollY="true" style="width: 100% !important;height:30% !important"> 
        <ion-refresher (ionRefresh)="fill_data($event)">
          <ion-refresher-content pullingIcon="arrow-dropdown" pullingText="{{ 'pull_to_refresh' | translate }}" refreshingSpinner="circles"
            refreshingText="{{ 'refreshing' | translate }}">
          </ion-refresher-content>
        </ion-refresher> 
        <ion-list>
          //data filling here
        </ion-list>
      </ion-scroll>
    </ion-content>
```

Please help me...

Comment: if you dont want scroll then why did you write <ion-scroll> inside <ion-content>

Comment: Hi, I dont want to scroll the whole content. I just want to scroll the list inside the ion-scroll only. There will have other components below ion-scroll which wont be scrolled.

Comment: @Tony are you saying ion-scroll is not scrolling?

Comment: @suraj ion-scroll is scrolling. Means both ion-scroll and ion-content are scrolling. I just need to stop the scrolling of ion-content.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I did it just now - same problem as you @Tony

With this SCSS my list scrolls, and I can have items below it:

```
page-home {
  .scroll-content {
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  ion-list {
    overflow-y: auto;
    max-height: 72vh;
  }
}
```

I tried using the ionic `scroll` and other options but none seem to work right now.

Answer (score 2):

```html
.scroll-content {
    overflow-y: hidden !important;
}
```

this worked for me

Answer (score 1):

use in the sass file of the page ..it works for me

```
.scroll-content {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    display: block;
    overflow-x: unset;
    overflow-y: unset;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    will-change: scroll-position;
    contain: size style layout;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Override the scroll-content, style

```
scroll-content {
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

i hope its work for you

Comment: Hi, Thank for your answer. But unfortunately its not solved. Still scrolling. I added like : page-home {
scroll-content {
    overflow-y: auto;
}
} in the home.scss which is the css of current page. and also added in content( <ion-content class="scroll-content" > ). Tried by adding class and without adding.

Comment: When I put the ion-list alone and override the scroll-content, its not scrolling. but it scrolls again when I add ion-scroll,ion-refresher and ion-list components.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-content>
   <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
        <ion-scroll style="width:100%;height:100px" scrollY="true">
           <ion-list scroll="true">
          <ion-item *ngFor="let item of testData">
            <div>{{item}}</div>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
        </ion-scroll>

      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>

  </ion-grid>
  <p>other data</p>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item>
      1
    </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
      1
    </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
      1
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

andin `.ts` file :

`testData = [];`

```
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
       for(let i =0;i<100;i++){
      this.testData.push(i);
    }
  }
```

check this [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/0zaHLSxK16fZ1IssBGYf?p=preview)

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the answer. Tried but still not fixing. Do you used ionic 2.0? My version is 3.2. could you try in 3.2 please?

Comment: No idea! its still not working here. When I put the ion-list alone and  override the scroll-content its not scrolling. but it scrolls again when I add ion-scroll,ion-refresher and ion-list components.

Comment: can you make a sample plunker or recreate issue in new project and upload to git

Answer (score 0):

Try below style code in your 'src\app\app.scss'

```
.scroll-content {
    overflow-y: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: This code is wrong. It should be hidden instead of auto. With auto you would be able to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

You can debug ios Ionic app using Safari, while debugging you can notice which is efficient.

```
.scroll-content {
    overflow-y: hidden !important;                                          
}
```

It will disable scrolling of ion-content and also disable scrolling of ion-list.

```
div.scroll-content {
    bottom: 0px !important;                                                   
}
```

It is more efficient to disable scrolling of ion-content. It prevents only ion-content but ion-list

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it. it's very simple.

```
ion-content > div.scroll-content {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

So it will be applied for only ion-content.